# handling exception in Triggers

Tags: trigger

I am facing an issue in handling exception in trigger.
Issue :

On creating a record in salesforce Out of the box functionality, one trigger is getting fired. trigger is trying to save records in different record but based on certain validation rule it restrict the record updation. its showing a long error

> CUSTOM_VALIDATION_ERROR

type message.

I need to handle the exception and populate an simplified error message which will help users to understand the issue. Please let me know the way I can handle this scenario and display a custom error message.

thanks
Ranjeet

Comment: whtever logic you wrote in custom validation.. Write same in trigger If satisfy then use sobject.addError method to display custom error message

Answer (score 1):

first put this code in try catch block

```
try{


...
}
catch(exception ex){
  sob.addError('Pass custom error here') //here sOb is instance of object
}
```

and then use `AddError` method to give your custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try catch for this. Put your update statement in try block and handle the exception in catch block. Here is an example below which I used to do the same thing.

```
 try 
        {
            if(!OppLineItemList.isEmpty())  //Place your condition here
            {
                update OppLineItemList;  //Update your List here
            }
        }
        catch(exception e) 
        {
            String S1 = e.getMessage();  //Get the error message here
            S1 = S1.substringBetween('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, ' , ': [');   //Modify the error message here. This line will handle all the Validation rules present for your object.
            Trigger.New[0].adderror(S1);   //Display a simplified error message.
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Regards! Ruchi

Comment: Please take note that you should not copy the `Trigger.New[0].addError(...` part blindly, as it put the error on 1st item on bulk update while the error might be triggered on 2nd... etc